# Placeholder When Query Builder Returns Null on Entity Type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've created a form with an EntityType field with a query builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $entity = $builder->getData();

    $relatedParentId = $entity->getParentEntity()->getId();

    $builder->add('myEntity', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => myEntity::class,
        'query_builder' => function(\AppBundle\Repository\myEntityRepository $eR) use ($relatedEntityId) {
            return $aR->getByParentId($relatedEntityId);
        },
    ))
}
```

When the query returns a value, it's fine. When null is returned however it shows on the form as just a blank option with a dropdown to nothing and is not very user friendly. I want to have a message to say no results have been returned.

Note that when a result is returned no message is required so the 'placeholder' option will not be enough. I'm possibly missing something obvious in the documentation but I've had with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use the placeholder option:

```
$builder->add('states', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => myEntity::class,
    'query_builder' => function(\AppBundle\Repository\myEntityRepository $eR) use ($relatedEntityId) {
        return $aR->getByParentId($relatedEntityId);
     }
    'placeholder' => $hasResults ? false : 'No results',
));
```

Where you build the hasResult flag before.

Comment: Do you think I would have to build the hasResult flag before with a seperate query or would there be a way to directly do it based on what's returned by the query builder?

Comment: In this cas, you could use a choice type instead of an entity type. So you can use the same date for building your choices array and using it for the `hasResults` flag, which will just be a `count($results)` in your case.